# "Generalized theory of polynomials" for a given commutative Lawvere Theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, universal-algebra

I am trying to understand 
[Nikolai Durov's "New Approach to Arakelov Geometry"](http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.2030) right now and it got me thinking about a particular thing.

Let $R$ be a commutative, associative ring with unit. We can associate two natural Lawvere theories to $R$:

1. We can make $T^{lin}_R$, the Lawvere theory we get by defining all $n$-ary operations to be formal linear combinations $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i$ in $n$ variables, with $a_i$ being elements of $R$. The only nullary operation is $0$.
2. We can make $T^{poly}_R$, the Lawvere theory we get by defining all $n$-ary operations to be polynomials in $n$ variables with coefficients in $R$

A model for $T^{lin}_R$ is exactly a $R$-module, a model for $T^{poly}_R$ is exactly an $R$-algebra. In fact we can use that as the definition of modules over $R$ (or $R$-algebras, respectively), which I think of as a nice little fact. An R-algebra is, after all, exactly something in which polynomials with coefficients in $R$ "make sense", same with modules and linear combinations.

Note further, that $T^{lin}_R$ is a commutative theory, while $T^{poly}_R$ is, unless in trivial cases, not. We can recover the ring $R$ in both cases; for $T^{lin}_R$, $R$ is the same as $hom_{T^{lin}_R}(x,-)$; we can interpret $hom_{T^{lin}_R}(x,x)$ as the underlying set of the ring, the multiplication is given by $\circ$ and addition by the interpretation of the linear combination $X+Y$ under $hom_{T^{lin}_R}(x,-)$. $x$ here is the generic object of $T^{lin}_R$. For $T^{poly}_R$, the ring $R$ can be found by $hom_{T^{lin}_R}(1,-)$, addition by $X+Y$, multiplication by $XY$.

Durov tries to generalize algebraic geometry by the first approach, calling a general commutative theory a *generalized ring*, this includes for example the field with one element $\mathbb{F}_1$, which is the lawvere theory generated by a single nullary operation.

Now, the second approach has been closer to me, since it naturally leads to the functor of points approach, where we take a Lawvere theory $T$, define the category $\mathbb{Aff}_T$ of affine $T$ spaces as the dual to it's category of models, $\mathbb{Aff}_T := \textbf{Mod}(T,\text{Set})^{op}$, and then view presheaves/sheaves with regard to various Grothendieck topologies on $\mathbb{Aff}_T$ as it's generalized schemes. For $T^{poly}_R$ this gives the usual schemes, for the Lawvere theory [CartSp](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/CartSp) with objects $\mathbb{R}^n$ and smooth mappings between them as morphisms we get $C^\infty$-schemes (of which smooth manifolds have a full embedding), taking $\mathbb{C}^n$ with holomorphic mappings we get a convenient category for complex differential geometry, etc.

My question is now the following: Is there a functor from commutative Lawvere theories to general Lawvere theories, which maps $T^{lin}_R$ to $T^{poly}_R$ for any commutative ring (or even better, rig) $R$ ? Can we view this functor as part of an adjunction?

Comment: There is a general procedure that derives the theory of $R$-modules from the theory of commutative $R$-algebras, but I do not know of a way to do the reverse.

Comment: Just to be explicit, I think @ZhenLin means that the category of R-modules is equivalent to the category of (Abelian) group objects in the slice over R of the category of Commutative R-algebras.

Comment: Yes, that is the procedure I am thinking of. It is a fact that the category of abelian group objects in the category of algebras for a Lawvere theory is itself equivalent to the category of algebras for a Lawvere theory (and, in particular, equivalent to the category of modules for a ring).

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed helpful. The way to make this precise is the fact that for two theories $T$ and $T'$ we have $\textbf{Mod}(T \otimes T', Set) \cong \textbf{Mod}(T,  \textbf{Mod}(T', Set))$. Is the slice category of Commutative $R$-Algebras over $R$ again a category of models for a Lawvere-Theory?

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that, if it is; and the relationship between the resulting Lawvere theory and $T^{poly}_R$ is functorial, I can take this functor, compose it with $T^{lin}_\mathbb{Z} \otimes -$, and have a candidate for the right adjoint of the adjoint situation I was looking for. EDIT: With the tensor product I mean of course <a href="http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensor+product+theory">the tensor product of algebraic theories</a>.

Comment: I'm sorry for the error, I'm new to overflow. The link I meant is of course ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensor+product+theory